# What is the core_url_rewrite from M1 called in M2?

Tags: magento2, database, url-rewrite

I wanted to do a bulk import of url rewrites but cannot find the proper table.

Comment: It's `url_rewrite` in Magento 2. Make a script or Import via CSV in DB

Comment: thanks! was doing a search for that but it was only searching the first page of tables. my bad.

Comment: do you know how one would go about getting the entity_id for this table? all i have is the url and apparently this new table requires entity_id or product_id.

Comment: In Magento 2 :- `entity_id` = 'product_id`. Can go ahead. Check `catalog_product_entity` Main Table for Products

Comment: What do you import into the url_rewrite, a table that requires and entity_id, if all you have is a path and some of the rewrites are for categories and content pages? Thanks again!

Comment: also, do you know of any resource that shows all the M2 tables and their relationships?